# Subscribing to the RSS feeds for only the most popular questions

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, feed

The default RSS feed (e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/feeds) appears to return just the most recent questions. It can be time-consuming to filter through.

Is it possible to only monitor those questions with X number of votes? Something similar to how [distill](http://www.distill.com) acts on feeds from digg.com?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Note that all tabs on the home page now have specific feeds.

Comment: I dont see it...

Comment: @midhat check the `<head>` tag in the HTML, or scroll to the bottom of the page and look for the orange RSS icon

Comment: Am I missing something? I don't see RSS anywhere.

Comment: Looks like they have been removed. There's only one Atom feed.